# Приложение не работает с api28 и выше

Tags: java, android

Приложение получает данные из интернета. Запускается и отлично работает на api25, но выше api28, включительно, нет.
Насколько я знаю, в >=api28 встроена защита против загрузки данных из http.
Как разрешить подключение?

Comment: Как именно оно не работает? Вылетает? Какие логи при этом выдает?

Answer (score 3):

Как оказалось, я просто не смог правильно сформулировать вопрос, поэтому не нашел на просторах нета ответ.
Собственно, решение на удивление простое. Для того, чтобы **разрешить все типы сетевых подключений HTTP и HTTPS** нужно добавить атрибут в манифест с разрешением всех http запросов:

```
<application>
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
<uses-library
    android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
    android:required="false" />
</application>
```